# Laravel 5 config locale, does not works

Tags: php, validation, laravel, locale, laravel-5

Modifications done:

on **config/app.php**

```
'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'en'),
'fallback_locale' => 'en',
```

on **.env**

```
APP_LOCALE=pt
```

I've also duplicated the **/resources/lang/en** files to **/resources/lang/pt** files as [docs suggests](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/localization).

**The problem:**

All my validation messages are still in english, and running **php artisan tinker**:

```
>>> Lang::getLocale()
=> "en"

>>> env('APP_LOCALE')
=> "pt"
```

Help?

Comment: Set on **config/app.php** does not works at all. And **php artisan env** returns **local** as configured on **.env**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already figured out how to solve that:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Session;
use App;
use Config;

class Locale {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        App::setLocale(env('APP_LOCALE'));
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

On **Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    .
    .
    .

    'App\Http\Middleware\Locale'
];
```

**UPDATE:**

My config was cached by command:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

So, I've done:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

And the middleware above isn't necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear 

php artisan config:cache
```

If you are using the `config:cache` command during deployment, you must make sure that you are only calling the `env()` from within your configuration files, and not from anywhere else in your application.

If you are calling env from within your application, it is strongly recommended you add proper configuration values to your configuration files and call env from that location instead, allowing you to convert your env calls to config calls.

Read whole thread over issue [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/21727).