# Laravel localization problem: the current language doesn't change

Tags: laravel, localization, laravel-8

when I want to change the current language for user I'm using:

```
App::setLocale($requestData['language']);
```

but when I'm trying to get current language in other functions it always returns the default language and it doesn't change, I'm using to get it:

```
$lang = App::currentLocale();
```

where is the problem? did I miss something?

edit: the full code

```
public function update_profile(Request $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user()->details;
    $requestData = $request->all();
    
    $details = UserDetail::where('id', $user->id)->update($requestData);
    $profile_progress = ListHelper::profile_progress();
    App::setLocale($requestData['language']);
    
    return response()->json([
        'message' => trans('messages.updated_successfully')
       
    ]);
}
```

and the other function:

```
public function onboarding()
{   
    $locale= App::currentLocale();
    return $locale;
}
```

Comment: Where exactly are you calling these methods?

Comment: in the controllers @Rwd

Comment: Try to binding with routes  - https://laraveldaily.com/multi-language-routes-and-locales-with-auth/

Comment: Please can you show all of the code for one of your controllers where you're doing this.

Comment: when I use App::currentLocale() in the same function, it returns the new language, but when I use it in other functions it returns the default, I have edited the question with full code @Rwd

Comment: in other controller @Rwd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524297/laravel-5-config-locale-does-not-works

Comment: Try to give a slash before `\App::setLocale....`