# Laravel & tailwind change Direction

Tags: laravel, vue.js, environment-variables, tailwind-css

My app is builded with Laravel 8, tailwindcss 3, vueJs 2 
I want add RTL support, but tailwind say that RTL support are currentlry in previw 
so I have th idea to change the `dir`attribute of `html`tag 
to do this I tried to change `locale`varible when I chnage the language of the user like this :

settingsController :

```
if ($key == 'language'){
       // \App::setLocale($value);
        putenv("APP_LOCALE=".$key);
        \Artisan::call('cache:clear'); // to clear cache
        \Artisan::call('config:clear'); // to clear config
    }
```

and I add the variable `APP_LOCALE` in `.env`file : `APP_LOCALE=`  but nothing to change

config/app.php : 
`'locale' => env('APP_LOCALE', 'en'),` 
my app.blade.php  :

```
<html lang="{{ \App::getLocale() }}" 
    dir="@if (\App::getLocale() == 'ar') rtl @endif" 
    class="h-full">
```

when I inspect code : `<html lang=" " dir="" class="h-full">`

Have an idea to fix that ?

Comment: Can you try `config()->set('app.locale','ar');` and remove `putenv`, `cache:clear`, `config:cache`?

Comment: Also you have `$key == 'language'` then `putenv("APP_LOCALE=".$key);` I don't think you want to have `language` in `APP_LOCALE`

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier it's a typo i set ` putenv("APP_LOCALE=".$value); `but nothing working,   I  also tried `config()->set('app.locale','ar');` also nothing

Comment: Side note: If you change the config in a request, it won't be preserved for the second request. You need to change the config in a middleware. Or is this the view returned from `SettingsController` ?

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier Yes I followed this disscussion [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29524297/laravel-5-config-locale-does-not-works] but sill not solution `app.locale`doesn't change

Comment: The fact that you have `lang=" "` and not `lang="en"` let me think something else's interfering in between. Or perhaps `$value` is a blank space. By the way, `App::setLocale(env('APP_LOCALE'));` from your link is a bad practice, the [`env()` will return `null` once `php artisan config:cache` is ran](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/configuration#configuration-caching).

Comment: @ClémentBaconnier no `$value`it's not empty It works with user_language in database, so the problem it's not with it, an fro `lang=" "`, I setted in `.env`  ` APP_LOCALE=fr` and it was not changed, also i comment `  \Artisan::call('config:clear'); ` but still nothing  to change ...